# find values which are the same as value above in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, rows

I am trying to find values which are the same as at least two values above it. Please take a look.

```
id       number
1        2
2        6
3        7
4        7
5        7
6        1
7        2
8        4
9        7
```

So in this case select would return:

```
ID      NUMBER
3        7
4        7
5        7
```

Comment: Are the `id` values consecutive?

Comment: Yes they are, always.

Comment: According to your description, only row 5 should be returned. Which one is correct, the description or the example?

Comment: First table is description how data is sorted. But yes, it would need to get out only row5 basically.  My example case is not the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up values in othe rows with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE number = (SELECT number
                FROM MyTable AS T2
                WHERE T2.id = MyTable.id - 1)
  AND number = (SELECT number
                FROM MyTable AS T2
                WHERE T2.id = MyTable.id - 2);
```

Comment: Hey, this is great, it works perfectly. Genious! Just please allow me to ask, is there any solution perhaps if you want to speed up process, with million ID values:) Thank you really for help.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.